# Alfresco attach Hyper links as document metadata

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created model in which I have defined an aspect with a property currently its type is text.

```
<property name="alfrescoDocs:sugarurl">
<title>SugarCrm URL</title>
<description>SugarCRM URL</description>
<type>d:text</type>                                 
</property>
```

I have successfully attached this aspect with document and update its property. but my requirement is to **attach hyper link** (anchor tag) with document as property. can any body help me how to do this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738652/how-to-add-links-in-property-sheet-in-alfresco ?

Comment: I have achieved this by adding new custom panels on my page on which I have added hyper links. following this http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/ewinlof/2011/11/09/add-remove-or-replace-components-on-shares-document-details-page/